# How do I extract a main class from an existing Java project?

Tags: java, program-entry-point, executable-jar, extract

I have a large Struts1 web project that also uses Hibernate.

One of our packages is:

`com.company.examples.users`.

Another is:

`com.company.examples.orders`.

Within each of those packages is a `main.java` file that is used for testing (actually running the file from within Netbeans).

So I can right-click the main files and tell it to run and the output is displayed in the log window.  That is fine.  But I want to be able to extract them out into actual JAR files so that they can be ran individually.

These files also rely on the entire, larger project.  Lots of packages, etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a jar? How about using the jar command?

Comment: Well, I'm sorta new to Java (C#/Ruby developer) so I guess yes.  I can create the massive WAR file to deploy to our web server but I need to extract a piece of it (the main.java classes) into separate JAR files.  Thanks

Comment: As you said, the main.java class is used to test the other classes. So they probably depend on all the other classes. You should thus create a single jar file containing all the classes. Isn't there someone in your organization who knows how Java works? There must be some build process to generate the war file, and this build process should be updated to generate the jar file.

Comment: Not really.  I'm sorta it.  We use Netbeans.  We click "clean and build" then copy the WAR file over.  That's why I'm stuck.  I'm trying to learn it but time constraints make it hard sometimes.  How do I create that single JAR file?  I only get the WAR file.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LF5cLVivV_Y how to crate a jar file with netbeans, google even found a video ;) Then use something like `java -cp <yourjar>.jar:<depending-lib>.jar:... my.package.main` to run the main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty dos way. Create a folder and `cd` into it.

```
>md test
>cd test
```

Copy your WAR file, the `prepare-tests.bat` and `make-classpath.bat` files into that folder.

Where `prepare-tests.bat` is:

```
md unpacked
cd unpacked
jar xvf ..\%1
cd WEB-INF\classes
jar cvf ..\..\..\classes.jar *
cd ..\..\..
call make-classpath
```

And `make-classpath.bat` is:

```
@echo off
<nul set /p =set CLASSPATH=.;> set-classpath.bat
<nul set /p =classes.jar;>> set-classpath.bat
for /f %%a IN ('dir unpacked\WEB-INF\lib *.jar /s/b') do <nul set /p =%%a;>> set-classpath.bat
```

Basically, these steps will unpack the WAR, jar up the WAR's classes (if any) and create a classpath that points to those classes plus all the JARs in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

You can then run tests (from within the `test` folder you created) by:

```
>prepare-tests my-war.war
>set-classpath
>java com.foo.bar.MyTest
```

You'd be much better off using tools like Maven and JUnit to automate/facilitate your testing though.

Comment: This actually worked.  But I went ahead and created a stand-alone java app and moved over what I needed.  This is a good reminder that we need to organize this stuff better.  :-)  Thanks\

Comment: Cool. Yeah it's best to try and build small components that do one job and do it well. Then they can be tested in isolation without the need for an app server. Some tests may of course need a web container to run, but you'll end up with much fewer of those.